# Insert date per row created within the date range beginning from startDate incrementing upto end date

Tags: javascript

I have been successful in creating a table whose rows will be generated according to the number of days between the start and end date. This is the code

```
var tabled = document.getElementById("table_data");
var newRowContent = '<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="numbersOnly" onchange="vdateRange()" placeholder=""/></td><td><input type="text" name="reading1" class="numbersOnly" onkeypress="validate(event)" /></td><td><input type="text" name="reading2" class="numbersOnly" onkeypress="validate(event)" /></td><td><input type="text" name="reading3" class="numbersOnly" onkeypress="validate(event)" /></td><td><input type="text" name="remark"/></td></tr>';
            //<button type="button" name="delete_row" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></button> #delete button
            //rows = table.insertRow(z);
             if (tabled.rows.length > 0) {
                $("#table_data tbody tr").remove(); 
                for(i = 0; i < z+1; i++){   
                    $('#table_data > tbody').append(newRowContent);

                }
```

I want to be able to insert date values beginning from the start date incrementing automatically as the rows are generated upto the end date please help

Comment: What does the variable 'tabled' refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Please see my solution below, I hope I have understood you requirements. The code defines currentDate as today, and adds it to the first table cell for each row, incrementing by a day as it goes. I hope it helps. (note: I have commented out a couple of lines to help me test)

```js
var tabled = document.getElementById("table_data");
var newRowContent = '';
            
//<button type="button" name="delete_row" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></button> #delete button
//rows = table.insertRow(z);

var currentDate = new Date();

//if (tabled.rows.length > 0) {
   $("#table_data tbody tr").remove(); 
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){   
     var nextDate = new Date(currentDate);
     nextDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1);
     newRowContent = '<tr><td>' + nextDate + '</td><td><input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="numbersOnly" onchange="vdateRange()" placeholder=""/></td><td><input type="text" name="reading1" class="numbersOnly" onkeypress="validate(event)" /></td><td><input type="text" name="reading2" class="numbersOnly" onkeypress="validate(event)" /></td><td><input type="text" name="reading3" class="numbersOnly" onkeypress="validate(event)" /></td><td><input   type="text" name="remark"/></td></tr>';
     $('#table_data tbody').append(newRowContent);
     currentDate = nextDate;
    }
//}
```